# Situation with pointers to chars

Tags: c

I am learning pointers to chars.

```
char ch[250];
char *ch2 = ch;
int z = 2;  // corrected this
int *z2;
z2 = &z;

scanf("%s", *ch2);
printf ("%c", *ch2[*z2]);
```

Is this correct way of working with char arrays?- or let me paraphrase the question, how can I print out the n-th symbol via pointers of arrays?

The input will be something like "asdjhkjhjh" - just characters
And the output will be "d" - as this is the 2-nd symbol from the entered input

Comment: Please specify your input and expected output.

Comment: `scanf("%s", *ch2);` --> `scanf("%s", ch2);`

Comment: What is `int z = "2";`supposed to to ? Compile with all warnings enabled.

Comment: also "d" is not the second symbol, but the symbol with the array index 2, which is the third symbol.

Comment: `int z = "2";` isn't valid C and should not compile. Your compiler is misconfigured or broken.

Comment: sure, I have corrected int z = 2;

Comment: Is this C or C++? Do you want to write in C++ or C?

Comment: printf `%s` expects a character pointer. But `*ch2` is the contents of a character pointer, that is a `char`. Anyway, SO is not an interactive beginner tutorial. Read about printf and pointers in your C book. Then after that, figure out how to enable all warnings on your compiler.

Comment: Please stop editing code while SO users are trying to understand it.  Do not transcribe code from whatever, copy/paste it from the code YOU BUILT AND TESTED.

Comment: @Lundin 'Your compiler is misconfigured or broken' - lol, politically-correct comment to avoid falling foul of the 'be nice' rule.

Comment: "pointers of arrays" is somethiong different. `ch` is and array and `ch2` is a "pointer to `char`". A "pointer **to** array of `char`" would be `char (*cp)[COLS];` which is something very different (use it for dynamically allocated 2D arrays).

Comment: @MartinJames I was not being sarcastic, this is a common problem. For example gcc only gives a warning for `int x = "this compiler is crap";`, even though this is a standard violation (as per the simple assignment rule, 6.5.something). It only behaves correctly if you have `-pedantic-errors` set.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to tell you, if you are right, if you don't say what you are trying to achieve with the code.

The:

```
printf ("%c", *ch2[*z2]);
```

in you code is equal to:

```
printf ("%c", *ch2[2]);
```

And it will print the third symbol.

If you are looking to print third symbol by using pointer arithmetics, you can use

```
printf ("%c", *(ch2 + 2));
```

The compiler knows, that ***ch2*** points to array of characters and character needs fixed length of memory, so it knows how to move pointer "2 sizes of character variable" to right.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf ("%c", *(ch2 + n));
```

The above statement will print n-th `char` in the array pointed to by `ch2`.

Comment: sorry dont understand, why n?

Comment: @Alex perhaps because you asked: *how can I print out the n-th symbol*

Comment: I understand that it is n-th char, just as you see, I am trying to use *ch2 with [*z2] = both are pointers

Comment: @Alex Because of pointer arithmetic. It is a messier, equivalent way of writing `ch2[n]`. Read about it in your C book. That being said, I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: The question is how to print n-th character using the pointer ch2. So, the answer is printf ("%c", *(ch2 + n));
@Alex What is wrong with this?

Comment: ch2 + n actually results in ch2 + (n * sizeof(char)). So, finally ch2 +n points to the n-th character in the array pointed to by ch2.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider the below code :

```
char *cp;
cp = "Stackoverflow";
int n = 2;
printf("\n%c",*(cp+n));
printf("\n%c",cp[n]);
```

both of print will write a , which is the 3rd offset (n+1) considering offset 0.